# How to get only published assets via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I want to get only the published assets from azure portal storage account.The problem in my case is that i have not any REST API end point which provide only the published assets.I am getting all the assets from azure account using REST API endpoint: 
   "https://storageAccountName.restv2.australiaeast.media.azure.net/api/Assets"

Comment: As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/asset#asset_entity_properties),can you try https://xxxx/Assets('Published')?

Comment: It's not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per a bit further down in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/operations/asset#publish_an_asset):
  The Publish action has been deprecated. Starting with the latest Media Services release, Publish should not be used.

If your code uses Publish, be aware of the following considerations:

1. The Publish action does not delete locators associated with the asset. You must explicitly delete the locators in code after calling Publish.
2. The Publish action does not set the asset state to Published. Remove the code that checks whether an asset is in the Published state. Currently, an asset can only have the Initialized or Deleted state.

Answer (score 1):

I dont actually recommend using the v2 APi for this type of query. V3 is better because the v2 only returns the top 1000. In v3 you can page through with the NextPage link if the list is really long.

WARNING on these types of queries though - You may be throttled if volume of such requests is too high. So if you plan to do this a lot, you may want to move the metadata to another DB (like Cosmos) for expensive queries.  AMS is not really an asset management system, and you should do more expensive UX level queries in another tier using the Asset ID as the foreign key.

This is what paging looks like in the v3 Client for .NET

var firstPage = await client.StreamingLocators.ListAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName);
var currentPage = firstPage;
while (currentPage.NextPageLink != null)
{
    currentPage = await MediaServicesArmClient. StreamingLocators.ListNextAsync(currentPage.NextPageLink);
}

You would need to get the Asset ID, and then also list through Streaming Locators that are using that Asset ID. Because there could be n-number of Streaming Locators published with that Asset ID.

Comment: How is that one asset can have multiple locators? I understood it was a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: No. You can have multiple locators. Each with their own filters on tracks or time as well as different content protection policies.